# What does "rig the herdway" mean?

Tags: meaning

It's from the 7th episode of the 7th season of *the Walking Dead*. Here is the context:

> Guy A: At least Negan's smart enough
>
> not to let that mess anywhere near us.
>
> Fat Joey's good for something, at least.
>
> Guy B: What, eating cake?
>
> He **rigged the herdway**.
>
> Just trips.

Comment: Is this scene available on YouTube or somewhere so we can hear the dialog as spoken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“herdway” seems to be a word invented by the show’s script writers. Given the show’s subject matter, I would guess it refers to some sort of path or channel (“way”) for a herd of zombies.

“rigged” means “put together”.

Combined, I would guess that “rigged the herdway” means put together some sort of physical obstacle to divert zombies around the speakers’ position.

Note: I haven’t watched the show at all; someone who has might have a completely different idea.

Comment: "Rigged' to me suggests something with an active mechanism; more complex than putting together some IKEA.  A weaker form of "engineered".  Ships sails are a good example, or traps - in this case, either tripwires (which, I'll admit, aren't especially active, unless they trigger a hidden trap), or at least tree branches and stuff that will trip the zombie herd.  (I don't watch the show, either, but I'm sure StephenS is right.)